# user(0) Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, youtube, typeerror, traceback

My name's Mitch. I've previously had some amazing help with maths and physics on stack exchange. I assume overflow is related but I realized I should keep this to one question. I've tried many times over to try to introduce myself to programming, particularly python, reading full book sized PDF's and extended YouTube videos, and keep tripping up on what must be really, really basic stuff.

So am trying once more, hoping the stack community can help me with these little trip ups. I'm not sure why you guys put so much energy into helping noobs like me learn things at no cost, but I appreciate that you do. Hopefully one day I will be proficient enough at something to give back. So here's my first question.

I have downloaded python 3.4.1. A lot of the tutorials out there seem to teach python 2.x but I'm pretty settled on 3. I'm on a Windows computer. I found a video series on you tube by thenewboston. I am using IDLE as is he. Where I've tripped up is in his version it goes:

```
>>> user = "Tuna McFish"
>>> user(0)

'T'
```

When I do it:

```
>>> user = "Tuna McFish"
>>> user(0)
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>   
user(0)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

(Sorry, not sure how to format properly for this site. What am I doing wrong?)

Comment: try `user[0]` user here is not a function by the way your first method should also throw error

Comment: the [0] worked. thank you!

Comment: you do know what you did wrong right you are trying to call it like a function

Comment: Still at the very basic level so yes and no but before it was () now it's []. I understand that print is a function and with print you use (). Also len for length. Still very basic like I say, I realise I sound like a spastic.

Comment: `method []` is mainly used for `slicing and indexing it is not a function call.It is also used to create list` `() is used to call function create function print is a function in 3.x it is also used to create tuple,generator and so on' Happy learning

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and programming in general. Do keep you hopes up, and be notified that in programming you need to be very precise, all of the different parenthesis have different meaning. In python you have, at least, the following basic meanings.

#### Square brackets `[]` for lists and slicing

See http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-python

```
>>> words = ['Some', 'different', 'words']
>>> words[1]
'different'
```

See http://www.dotnetperls.com/slice

```
>>> words[:2]          # Slice of two first elements
['Some', 'different']
```

***NB!** Note that square brackets are also used for dereferencing various stuff, like dicts, tuples, lists, and so on...*

#### Curly braces `{}` for dict's or sets

See http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-python

```
>>> lookup = { 1 : 'First', 2: 'Second', 3: 'Third' }
>>> lookup[1]       # NB! Using square brackets for looking up
'First'
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/set-python

```
>>> colors = { 'red', 'green', 'blue'}
>>> 'red' in colors
True
```

#### Ordinary parentheses `()` for tuples, functions, grouping, ...

See http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple-python

```
>>> block = ( '10th East Street', '30th North Avenue') 
>>> horizontal, vertical = block  
>>> horizontal
'10th East Street'
>>> vertical
'30th North Avenue'
>>> block[0]       # NB! Using square brackets for dereferencing
'10th East Street'
```

In functions, see http://www.dotnetperls.com/def

```
>>> print('a function call')
a function call
```

In grouping, see http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-python  in "and/or" section

```
>>> a, b, c = True, False, True
>>> a and (b or c)
True
```